# PowerShell Modul SqlServer

Tags: powershell, module

I'm running module: SQLSERVER (Version 20), get-help online says there is a parameter "credential", but there is not in this module I imported?
Thanks for help.

Comment: What are you trying to do? For instance the command 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' has a parameter "-Credential". But the module itself is just the module...

Comment: I'm running:
import-module -name sqlserver -NoClobber -disablenamechecking
$cred = get-credential
Invoke-sqlcmd -serverInstance "mySQL" -Database "myDB" -credential $cred -query "select * from ...."
and getting an error: a parameter 'credential" could not be found"

Comment: If you just type Invoke-SqlCmd and then a '-' you will see all available options. Are you typing this all in 1 line? Otherwise try Powershell_ISE and press cntrl + r. You will be able to have more oversight

Comment: Another comment, try leaving out -Credential and use -Username and -Password instead

Comment: yes, indeed, I'm using a dash '-' to see the options, sorry for my irony...
using -username and -password is the wrong way, cos I don't want to use SQL Server credentials but Domain-credentials.

Comment: You could try running powershell as a different user (shift-rightmouseclick -> run as different user) and leave the -Credential and -Username and -Password out!

Comment: wrong way, it should be a part of a quite long script. Still the point: what about the parameter -credential, why it is not there?

Comment: Maybe try to re-install the module? I see no reason why the parameter is absent to be honest...